# UITableView acting up when trying to delete a cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController, when I try swiping to delete a cell and press delete, it then turns the cell to edit mode and shows the red arrow on the left.  But the data has been deleted already.  Because when I restart the app it is gone.  Does anything in my code look suspect?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    [self.tableView setEditing: !self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
     {
         PFObject *routine= [self.routineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [routine deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 [self.tableView reloadData];
             } else {
                 // There was an error saving the gameScore.
             }
         }];   
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the item from your dataSource `self.routineArray`, then delete it from the tableView using `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, then remove it from your Core Data store.  The order is important because you can't delete it from the tableView if it still exists in your dataSource or an exception will be thrown due to the tableView being out of sync with the number of items it's dataSource.

In this example, it is first deleted from the Data Store, then from the dataSource, then removed from the tableView, which should work as well.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        PFObject *routine= [self.routineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [routine deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                [self.routineArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            } else {
                // There was an error saving the gameScore.
            }
        }];   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked, but the animation is still setup.  When I swipe then press delete, it shows the minus sign on the left, then finally deletes teh cell.

Comment: This is what I meant by the order is important. What are you returning for `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`? You must ensure that the number being returned in that dataSource method is the same as the number of rows in the table view. If at any time the tableView calls this method and the number differs, it will throw `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. Are you using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage the table view by any chance? Try deleting the object from `self.routineArray` and removing the row from the tableView first and make sure you do not run `[tableView reloadData]`

Comment: I'm not getting the crash anymore, but the animation is messed up. I made a new question for it here with a video if you can take a  look. Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976249/stange-animation-when-deleting-uitableviewcell